# cannot resolve context after importing android.content.Context; The Toast

Tags: java, android

This is my code block and I attached an Image . I don't know why "text" and .show() looks red.

Code Block:

```
private void setUpListViewListener() {
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            //Context context = getApplicationContext();


            Toast.makeText(context, text: "Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            items.remove((i));
            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;


        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `text:`. That's not supposed to be in the actual code. It's just a parameter hint that you're likely seeing in a screenshot or video of someone else's IDE.

Comment: Simply do this         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its Syntext error

Syntext is  -> Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Removed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```